# Add leading 0 to single digit integers using .sprintf?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Found another question that seemed to be solved by using .sprintf('%02d', 1) to solve this, but I get: 'private method `sprintf' called for 7:Fixnum'.

Does this mean sprintf cant be called on an integer or am I getting it wrong in the calling?

Just looking to pad single digit returns with a leading 0.

Thanks in advance for any help on this!

Comment: Yes, it's not a method of integer.

Comment: Do you know of an alternative that might work with integers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may want to try `"0#{num}"[-2..-1]` or `"%02d" % 1`

Comment: sorry to be slow, but how to I implement this without calling .sprintf as it doesn't work with integers...? Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: i think you're using `7.sprintf...`. am i right? If I am, replace the whole code code (starting at 7) with either one of the suggestions above.

Comment: I'm calling sprintf on a query that returns an integer (just happens to be 7 in this instance). model.count.sprintf etc... cant thank you enough for even trying!

Comment: then use `"0#{model.count}"[-2..-1]` or `"%02d" % model.count`

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try using sprintf like this:

```
sprintf('%02d', 1)
# => "01"
```

ie

```
sprintf('%02d', model.count)
```

Not calling `.sprintf` on the number but rather inputing it as a parameter into `sprintf()`